# How to create Employee Status with Ratechangedate and EndDate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL
In AdventureWorks2008R2 Database,

I `Left Join Employee+EmployeePayHistory+EmployeeDepartmentHistory... tables`
and also create a column call Status,

I want to use Status to set `"Current"/"Expired"` (or Null) with condition below

Condition:

RateChangeDate in EmployeePayHistory Table and EndDate in EmployeeDepartmentHistory Table.

When EndDate is not null, set Status as Expired (or Null).

When EndDate is null, then check RateChangeDate, if only have one record, set Status to Current, if have multiple records, the latest date of RateChangeDate, set Status to Current, other record set Status to Expired (or Null).

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please provide your query what you have tried and error you got but provide your efforts and query .

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do it. Do you have any idea?